# Resizing “VM” APFS volume on osx

Tags: disk-utility, mojave, partition, disk-space, disk-format

I'm trying to free up space but 150gb is taken by "other volumes".

`diskutil list` shows that "VM" volume is taking 150gb.

How can I resize it to be smaller?

[image]

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         249.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume osx                     93.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                522.7 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      148.7 GB   disk1s4 <--- too big?
```

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: That looks like Mojave. I looked at mine - VM is 20.5**KB**

Comment: @nohillside yes Mojave v10.14.4

Comment: In any case, it has to be under Catalina 10.15 because the system partition is not on it.  Maybe the medium could be deleted.  diskutil eraseVolume "JHFS+" VM /dev/disk1s4 (VM volume: Used by macOS to swap file storage.)